# get parameters of JAR installer

Tags: executable-jar, silent-installer

I have a jar file that allows me to install some software, this JAR request me to fill many fields everytime. 
I need to write a script or something to fill this data automatically. I know how to pass parameters to the JAR file but I dont know the parameters name so how can I get the parameters name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about taking the input from a text file?

```
java -jar installer.jar <input.txt
```

with `input.txt` the consecutively asked inputs:

```
first-line
second-line
42
```

The `< ...` takes standard input from a file, `> ...` writes stdout, `2> ...`  writes stderr to a file.

You can also make a java class doing that with `System.setIn(InputStream)`.